# Microphone stopped being detected

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10

I have no idea how or why it happened. The video portion of the webcam works but not the microphone which used to work before.

Microphone works on Windows by the way, just stopped working on Ubuntu 12.10.

Webcam is a LifeCam VX-5500.

Here's some log files for now:

### dmesg Log

```
Jan  3 15:47:17 dnb kernel: [  901.502555] usb 2-1.7: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
Jan  3 15:47:17 dnb kernel: [  901.683560] usb 2-1.7: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=072d
Jan  3 15:47:17 dnb kernel: [  901.683566] usb 2-1.7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan  3 15:47:17 dnb kernel: [  901.683570] usb 2-1.7: Product: Microsoft® LifeCam VX-5500
Jan  3 15:47:17 dnb kernel: [  901.683573] usb 2-1.7: Manufacturer: Microsoft
Jan  3 15:47:17 dnb mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7"
Jan  3 15:47:17 dnb mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Jan  3 15:47:17 dnb kernel: [  901.690746] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Microsoft® LifeCam VX-5500 (045e:072d)
Jan  3 15:47:17 dnb kernel: [  901.692781] input: Microsoft® LifeCam VX-5500 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7/2-1.7:1.0/input/input18
```

Here's my:

### lsmod | grep snd_

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32007  4 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   127949  1 
snd_hda_intel          33277  5 
snd_hda_codec         126899  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm_oss            45541  0 
snd_seq_oss            34148  0 
snd_mixer_oss          22414  1 snd_pcm_oss
snd_pcm                96369  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_oss
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_oss
snd_seq                61521  4 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29370  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14497  2 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq
snd                    82952  22 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm_oss,snd_seq_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
```

And last but not least:

### lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1241:1166 Belkin MI-2150 Trust Mouse
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 045e:072d Microsoft Corp.
```

Let me know what I can try or if you guys need more information to rectify this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This maybe elementry, but... have you tried another USB port?  More specificly, are you using a USB 3.0 port instead of 2.0?  USB 3, from what I gather, is still a maturing technology and not sure if the kernel best supports it.

Comment: Yeap, tried all of them actually. Haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling all the kernels `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-*` and using a Live CD to run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) fixed my issue.